# Emacs setup for fortran

Tags: emacs, fortran

I currently work on a big Fortran project with emacs, but I have the feeling that my current setup is inadequate to the task.

I use f90-mode with auto-complete (without fortran-specific setup, so I only have completion for opened files), and I really miss function header information on hover (as in elisp code), code-folding, lists of subroutines in the current buffer, lists of included files, info on the origin of subroutines and used variables (C-xC-f to open the source file?), …

How can I best add modern supporting functionality for fortran in my emacs?

Mostly I need tools which help me *understanding* the projects code.

The project uses its own build tool and copies files from different directories into a build directory before building, actually overwriting some files with different versions of the code, so I need a quite flexible tool which can cope with that.

Answer (score 5):

There's a small Emacs plugin called [Fortran-tags](https://github.com/raullaasner/fortran-tags). It can find the definition of any variable or procedure under the cursor, so it's similar to Ctags, except that it is able to correctly identify all local and global variables and has some additional features. Also, it is developed with the focus on modern Fortran.

Comment: sounds great! I’ll be sure to test it when I work on the Fortran codebase again!

Comment: I will say just in case that it's for Linux only at this point. (Probably not too difficult to port it to others.)

Comment: Man, I have been struggling to find half decent fortran tag support in Emacs for a long time. I’ve been doing things like defining custom regexps for etags, trying GNU Global/ggtags combined with pygments, and trying to figure out how to at least use imenu for tags, but this actually looks like an acceptable out-of-the-box solution. Thanks so much for posting it here.

Comment: OK, it seems that the Fortran-tags project is quite buggy/hacky/unrobust. First of all it appears to require python3 due to some non-standard use of str.split with keywords. Second of all when new files are added to the list of files to process and FORTAGS is updated, the new file is added to the list of files at the top, but the tags from that file are not added. Lastly when ising ISO_C_BINDING stuff I get `File "/usr/local/bin/fortran-tags.py", line 314, in process_input
    position = int((m.start()+m.end())/2)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'start'`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'll try to fix any bugs as soon as possible. Yes, it indeed requires python3, where the use of keywords as you have pointed out is in fact allowed. This is now mentioned in the documentation to avoid further confusion. I removed the keywords and it now seems to work with python2, although I can't guarantee full compatibility.

Comment: As for your other comments, I haven't experienced neither of the issues. Perhaps you are using some nonstandard elements in your code? Fortran-tags definitely doesn't work with every possible source code (this would require compiler level complexity). I've made efforts for compatibility with older standards and some nonstandard ways of coding, but some assumptions about the coding style are still made. For information, I'm using the Abinit and Quantum Espresso and any of my own projects for reference when developing Fortran-tags. Lets continue this conversation at sourceforge.

Answer (score 3):

Using [fortran-language-server](https://github.com/hansec/fortran-language-server) (after installation simply start `fortls` in the terminal) and [lsp-mode](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode) in emacs works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

I now found the f90-interface-browser in elpa.

If you use emacs 24 or later, you can just use

```
M-x package-list-packages
```

and then search for `f90-interface-browser`.

> You write (or work on) large, modern fortran code bases.  These
>   make heavy use of function overloading and generic interfaces.  Your
>   brain is too small to remember what all the specialisers are
>   called.  Therefore, your editor should help you.

Comment: this package is useless, AFAICT. Check out yasnippet and smart-tab and others

Comment: Does anyone know if there is any, perhaps ongoing, work to include Fortran (>=90, hopefully 2003(8))  in the built-in emacs support and by that I mean CEDET/Semantic?